# Counting the occurrences of names using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Sorry I am new to VBA. The Vlookup calls for Column X & Y work fine. However, for column Z, I am trying to count the number of names in Column B, but an error kept popping up. I wonder why?

```
Dim lastrow As Long
lastrow = Range("A2").End(xlDown).Row

Range("X2:X" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-23],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R25000C10,7,0)"
Range("Y2:Y" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC[-24],'Sheet2'!R1C1:R25000C10,2,0)"
Range("Z2:Z" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-22]-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-22], "";"", ""))+1"
Columns("X:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Basically, what I am try to achieve is like the following. Column Z will autofill the occurrences of names in column B

[image]

Comment: what is the error thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing a parenthese in your function string, as well as escape quotes for the empty string, so it should be:

```
 Range("Z2:Z" & lastrow).FormulaR1C1 = "=LEN(RC[-22])-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(RC[-22], "";"", """"))+1"
```

Comment: Sorted! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I realize that this answer doesn't answer your question but at least the following code  serve the same purpose. And to fix the problem if there are blanks or merged cells in the range as pointed out by Mr. RGA, I change the way to formulate variable `Last_Row`

```
    Sub Count_Name()
    Dim i As Long, Last_Row As Long
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        'It won't be a problem anymore if there are blanks or merged cells in the range using this line
        Last_Row = Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To Last_Row
           If .Cells(i, "A") = "" Then
                .Cells(i, "B") = 0
           Else
                .Cells(i, "B") = Len(.Cells(i, "A")) - Len(Replace(.Cells(i, "A"), ";", "")) + 1
           End If
       Next i
    End With
    End Sub
```

Here I'm assuming the string names are in **column A**, the number of names are in **column B**,  and both of the data are in **Sheet1**. The equivalent Excel formula for the above code is

```
=LEN(A2) - LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2, ";", "")) + 1
```

Comment: This won't work properly if there are blanks or merged cells in the range

Comment: @RGA Well, I clearly stated "Here I'm assuming the string names in **column A** and the number of names in **column B**" in my answer. That's why I provided the Excel formula, too.

Comment: OP already had the Formula in their code, that wasn't their problem.  And the reason it would fail is your `End(xlDown)` call.  If you don't believe me, go into a sheet, merge a few cells, start above them and see where `End(xlDown)` sends your selection. (Hint: It will select the merged cell even if there are contiguous values past that)

Comment: And the sentence you quoted to me isn't even grammatically correct.  What are you assuming?  You're missing an active verb

Comment: @RGA Sorry Sir, I'm an ESL speaker

Comment: I realize reading what I sent that it sounds aggressive, which was not my intention.  Just trying to help you clarify your own answer

Comment: @RGA Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. I wish I were good at speaking English so that I could convey my thought and convert it to the answer

Comment: Having seen your answers in Mathematics, it is definitely clear that you are more intelligent than your english alone conveys.  Keep practicing at it and I'm sure your contributions will be recognized :)

Comment: @RGA Thanks for the vote of confidence, I really appreciate it :)

Comment: @RGA I fix my code. I think the blanks or merged cells in the range won't be a problem anymore if any